# Updated JSF app and now it's failing due to encryption-related issue

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

A work colleague updated our system to use Mojarra JSF 2.2.1 from JSF 1.something and to Primefaces 5.1 from Primefaces 4.  It was tested in our dev environment without problem but when it went live, we got lots of security-related errors such this one:

```
Dec 09, 2014 5:26:13 PM com.sun.faces.renderkit.ByteArrayGuard encrypt
SEVERE: Unexpected exception initializing encryption.  No encryption will be performed.
java.security.ProviderException: update() failed
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Mac.engineUpdate(P11Mac.java:241)
```

Also, some other JSF/Primefaces errors like the view state expiring.  We're pretty sure this is due to a failure to encrypt the view state on the client side.  What could have caused this?  Our sys admin tried some configuration tweaks and tried updating our Java security libraries, but that didn't work. I'm thinking that we should change the STATE_SAVING_METHOD in web.xml from client to server so that it doesn't do the encrypting in the first place.  Does that sound like a good solution?  I'm worried about memory issues though.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Client state saving has several drawbacks including extra cpu consumption (for serialization) and extra network usage. Using server side state saving is the way to go for production systems. That will increase memory usage. From what I've seen, you should plan for 5MB sessions to be on the safe side.

Comment: thanks for your input.  I'm worried because we're not doing lazy loading and some of the tables we have are huge.